Excel to convert multiple lines in a single cell
Is there a way to do so in Excel?
My Excel:

My desired output:


If it has to be a formula then why not use SUBSTITUTE() function and why take a long route to split and join. Will it be quicker to use multiple functions as against one function. Or will it be not right just to use native feature of Excel by replace and find.

Select the range you want to fix.
Press Ctrl+H to bring up the Find/Replace dialog.
In the 'Find What' box, type Ctrl+Shift+J. This will enter a line break.
In the 'Replace with' box, type your semi-colon.
Hit 'Replace all'.


This is the best answer if it needs to be done once.

Never knew about ctrl+shift+J to put a line break as input value. Thanks for sharing.

Once used, and typing the semi colon in the find what, it errors saying: "We couldn't find anything to replace". It seems the  line break is still there if we use backspace or select all to overwrite the find value. Is there a combination we should use to undo/delete the line break character from as input value?

I was able to press Ctrl+A in the Find What field and then delete to remove it.

This is brilliant.  Where in the world did you discover that ctrl-shift-j is a line break? Do you know if it detects all variants (Cr, Lf, CrLf)?  Or does Excel have a line break standard?

I believe Ctrl+Shift+J inserts a soft line break which is more flexible in different locales. Ctrl+J inserts CRLF.

=TEXTJOIN("; " , TRUE, TEXTSPLIT(B1 , CHAR(10)))

This should do the trick: it first gets rid of the ALT+Enter line and then combines with "; ".
If this doesn't work, try and find out which line splitting character is used and change it in the formula as required.

This is the best answer if it needs to be done routinely and / or automatically.
